# How to query a many to many relationship with an array of ID's in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, many-to-many

Say there are stores, customers, and credit accounts. So customers and stores have a many-to-many relationship through the credit account table.

If I want every customer that has an account at a given store, I could access it like follows.

```
var customers = dbContext.Customers
    .Where(c => c.CreditAccounts.Select(a => a.StoreID).Contains(storeID));
```

That seems to work but when I want to search by multiple storeIds, I get an empty result set. Here are some things I've tried.

```
var customers = dbContext.Customers
    .Where(c => c.CreditAccounts.Any(a => storeIDs.Contains(a.StoreID)));
```

And

```
var customers = dbContext.Customers
    .Where(c => c.CreditAccounts.Select(a => a.StoreID).Intersect(storeIDs).Count() > 0);
```

These always give me empty results. How can I achieve this without writing a raw SQL query?

**Update**

I did not have the data that I thought I had. Once that was corrected, my queries began to work. I think the question is still valid though because it's not clear whether any of these perform well, so other users might wish to respond with the most efficient way to retrieve the results.

Comment: What do you get if you do this `var hasAccounts = dbContext.CreditAccounts.Any(a => storeIDs.Contains(a.StoreID))`?

Comment: That would assume that `CreditAccount` has multiple `storeIDs` but it only has one. I think what you meant is `var hasAccounts = dbContext.CreditAccounts.Any(a => a.StoreID == storeID))`

This does indeed return true as I expect. Notice that the first query in my post works fine, returning all customers for one store ID.

Comment: I'm confused. That's your code. And it does not assume `CreditAccount` has multiple `storeID`s. Rather, it checks if any of the `CreditAccount`s has a `storeID` that is in your `storedIDs` which I presume is a collection.

Comment: It seems that I did read your comment wrong so that's my mistake, sorry!

Comment: Ok so yes, that will return true in my scenario as I expect. Sorry I got confused :(

Comment: Is your `storeIDs` a Queryable?

Answer (score 2):

The following linq query will return the results that you are looking for - however, I am not certain that it will perform well at all:

```
var results = dbContext.Customers
    .Where(c => c.CreditAccounts.Join(storeIds.ToList(), a => a.StoreId, s => s, (a,s)=>s).Any());
```

You may get better performance by finding the credit accounts that intersect with the StoreID, and then joining the list of credit accounts with the customers table - although I can't tell from the code you have provided whether you have direct access to a list of creditaccounts.

Comment: If I understand this correctly the sql would look like `SELECT * FROM Customers INNER JOIN CreditAccounts ON CreditAccounts.StoreId IN (<comma_separated_store_ids>)`, is that right? That would make sense.

Comment: Also, querying against just `CreditAccount` and then mapping to the `Customer` does sound doable. Thanks!